# Python count exclusion of specific object

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the following problem that I would be grateful for some help.

```
a =[['911', 'strength', 'Bolero lists 12 pounds hassle free and stress free.'], ['912', 'power', 'Bolero lifts free weights.']]

b = ['free', 'Bolero', 'pounds']
```

What I'm doing is appending the number of hits for b in a to a. Please see the code below:

```
c = []


for sent in a:
    o = 0
    for i in sent:
        o +=sum(i.count(col) for col in b)
    c.append((sent, o))
```

The result is:

```
c =[(['911', 'strength', 'Bolero lists 12 pounds hassle free and stress free.'], 4), (['912', 'power', 'Bolero lifts free weights.'], 2)]
```

The tricky thing is trying to exclude "hassle free" from the count for "free" in list b.

So in essence the result set would be:

```
c =[(['911', 'strength', 'Bolero lists 12 pounds hassle free and stress free.'], 3), (['912', 'power', 'Bolero lifts free weights.'], 2)]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is it `1` on the second? And why to exclude "hassle free"? Do you want to match each word only once?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. It was a typo.

Comment: Subtract `i.count("hassle free")` from the `sum`?
`o += sum(i.count(col)for col in b) - i.count("hassle free")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `"hassle free"` count from every string in `a`. You could substract it in the `for` loop:

```
for sent in a:
    o = 0
    for i in sent:
        o += sum(i.count(col) for col in b)
        o -= i.count("hassle free")
    c.append((sent, o))
```

**Output:**

```
[(['911', 'strength', 'Bolero lists 12 pounds hassle free and stress free.'], 3), (['912', 'power', 'Bolero lifts free weights.'], 2)]
```

Comment: Ok Christian, the way you have gone about it opens a lot of possibilities. I know it's trivial for you but this definitely helps. I can now add more phrases to the exclusion list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `count` each item from `b` only once, you could do something like:

```
for sent in a:
    o = 0
    for word in b: # loop over b, so each item counted only once
        for s in sent: # work through sentence
            if word in s:
                o += 1
                break # add one only
    c.append((sent, o))
```

Which could be shortened using a list comprehension:

```
c = [(sent, sum(any(word in s for s in sent) for word in b)) for sent in a]
```